# how to add checkbox value as json data

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a custom module for a form. And  I have json data which I want to add as checkbox values.

```
$request = drupal_http_request($url);
$jsonarray =drupal_json_decode($request->data);
print_r($jsonarray);
 foreach($jsonarray as $info) {
$output1 =$info[0];
$output2 =$info[1];
$output3 =$info[2];
}

 echo $output1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

`'#checked' => !empty($default_value)?1:0,`

in your form checkbox field.